# Optimizing Query Design Teradata

Tags: sql, vba, teradata, ado

I'm being asked to automate something fast because someone is retiring.  The process has hundreds of queries and upon a quick overview of the code could definitely be done better but they want it by the end of the month which doesn't leave me time to fix.

Our Teradata environment has DB admins aborting queries that exceed 20k cpu usage.  So far I've gotten to the 60th step with multiple loops to populate volatile tables and I have the following step.

```sql
create volatile table IATA as (  
  SELECT                                                                                                                                                
      b."DOM/INTL- pos",  
      a.REV,  
      a.RPM,  
      a.TKTNG_ARLN_CD,  
      a.PARENT_PNR,  
      a.PNR_CREATE_DT,  
      a.Fare_Product,  
      a.SPACE_HELD,  
      a.TKTD_PAX,  
      a.UNTKTD_PAX,  
      a.XNCL_DT,  
      a.DAYS_HELD,  
      a.DPTR_DT,  
      a.BKG_TYPE,  
      a.create_to_dept,  
      a.create_to_xncl,  
      a.cancel_to_dept,  
      a.HOME_OFFICE_IATA,  
      a.SUB_OFFICE_IATA,  
      b.COUNTRY_NAME  
  FROM GQI_COM28_IATA a  
      right join IATA1 b  
      on a.PARENT_PNR = b.PARENT_PNR  
      and a.PNR_CREATE_DT = b.PNR_CREATE_DT  
      WHERE a.pnr_create_dt between date-1085  and date - 1   
  ) with data no primary index ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;
```

I've attempted breaking the above into a loop using the btet and looping one day at a time using VBA as below:

```vb
Public Function GQI_62 ()        
QueryStringX = ""
QueryStringX = QueryStringX & "  "

QueryStringX = QueryStringX & "  create volatile table IATA as (  "
QueryStringX = QueryStringX & "  SELECT                                                                                                                                                "
QueryStringX = QueryStringX & "      b.""DOM/INTL- pos"",  "
QueryStringX = QueryStringX & "      a.REV,  "
QueryStringX = QueryStringX & "      a.RPM,  "
QueryStringX = QueryStringX & "      a.TKTNG_ARLN_CD,  "
QueryStringX = QueryStringX & "      a.PARENT_PNR,  "
QueryStringX = QueryStringX & "      a.PNR_CREATE_DT,  "
QueryStringX = QueryStringX & "      a.Fare_Product,  "
QueryStringX = QueryStringX & "      a.SPACE_HELD,  "
QueryStringX = QueryStringX & "      a.TKTD_PAX,  "
QueryStringX = QueryStringX & "      a.UNTKTD_PAX,  "
QueryStringX = QueryStringX & "      a.XNCL_DT,  "
QueryStringX = QueryStringX & "      a.DAYS_HELD,  "
QueryStringX = QueryStringX & "      a.DPTR_DT,  "
QueryStringX = QueryStringX & "      a.BKG_TYPE,  "
QueryStringX = QueryStringX & "      a.create_to_dept,  "
QueryStringX = QueryStringX & "      a.create_to_xncl,  "
QueryStringX = QueryStringX & "      a.cancel_to_dept,  "
QueryStringX = QueryStringX & "      a.HOME_OFFICE_IATA,  "
QueryStringX = QueryStringX & "      a.SUB_OFFICE_IATA,  "
QueryStringX = QueryStringX & "      b.COUNTRY_NAME  "
QueryStringX = QueryStringX & "  FROM GQI_COM28_IATA a  "
QueryStringX = QueryStringX & "      right join IATA1 b  "
QueryStringX = QueryStringX & "      on a.PARENT_PNR = b.PARENT_PNR  "
QueryStringX = QueryStringX & "      and a.PNR_CREATE_DT = b.PNR_CREATE_DT  "
QueryStringX = QueryStringX & "      WHERE a.pnr_create_dt between date-10  and date - 0   "
QueryStringX = QueryStringX & "  ) with data no primary index ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS;  "


Call Variants.Query_X


QueryStringX = " "
QueryStringX = QueryStringX & "BT;  "

x = 0
For i = 1 To 1085
    x = x + 1
    If i < 108 Then y = x + 9
    If i = 108 Then y = 1085


QueryStringX = QueryStringX & "  insert into IATA  "
QueryStringX = QueryStringX & "  SELECT                                                                                                                                                "
QueryStringX = QueryStringX & "      b.""DOM/INTL- pos"",  "
QueryStringX = QueryStringX & "      a.REV,  "
QueryStringX = QueryStringX & "      a.RPM,  "
QueryStringX = QueryStringX & "      a.TKTNG_ARLN_CD,  "
QueryStringX = QueryStringX & "      a.PARENT_PNR,  "
QueryStringX = QueryStringX & "      a.PNR_CREATE_DT,  "
QueryStringX = QueryStringX & "      a.Fare_Product,  "
QueryStringX = QueryStringX & "      a.SPACE_HELD,  "
QueryStringX = QueryStringX & "      a.TKTD_PAX,  "
QueryStringX = QueryStringX & "      a.UNTKTD_PAX,  "
QueryStringX = QueryStringX & "      a.XNCL_DT,  "
QueryStringX = QueryStringX & "      a.DAYS_HELD,  "
QueryStringX = QueryStringX & "      a.DPTR_DT,  "
QueryStringX = QueryStringX & "      a.BKG_TYPE,  "
QueryStringX = QueryStringX & "      a.create_to_dept,  "
QueryStringX = QueryStringX & "      a.create_to_xncl,  "
QueryStringX = QueryStringX & "      a.cancel_to_dept,  "
QueryStringX = QueryStringX & "      a.HOME_OFFICE_IATA,  "
QueryStringX = QueryStringX & "      a.SUB_OFFICE_IATA,  "
QueryStringX = QueryStringX & "      b.COUNTRY_NAME  "
QueryStringX = QueryStringX & "  FROM GQI_COM28_IATA a  "
QueryStringX = QueryStringX & "      right join IATA1 b  "
QueryStringX = QueryStringX & "      on a.PARENT_PNR = b.PARENT_PNR  "
QueryStringX = QueryStringX & "      and a.PNR_CREATE_DT = b.PNR_CREATE_DT  "
QueryStringX = QueryStringX & "      WHERE a.pnr_create_dt = date-" & i & "  "
'QueryStringX = QueryStringX & "      WHERE a.pnr_create_dt between date-" & y & " and date-" & x & "  "
QueryStringX = QueryStringX & " ;  "

'Call Variants.Query_X
    
x = y

Next i


QueryStringX = QueryStringX & "  ET; "
'QueryStringX = QueryStringX & "sel count(*) AS CntR from IATA1  "

Call Variants.Query_X

On Error Resume Next
    If Not (rs Is Nothing) Then
      If (rs.State And adStateOpen) = adStateOpen Then
      rs.Close
      End If
      Set rs = Nothing
    End If

End Function
```

The above worked well for a test of a few days but errors with the full 1085 because the query is being aborted.  So I decided to give this a try and hope dieter sees and can help with any ideas or good advice within the given context?

This is the query call which I've optimized and used for many years from the above.

```vb
Public ns As ADODB.Connection
Public rs As ADODB.Recordset
Public connector As String
Public QueryStringX As String

Public GRPcntR As Integer
Public FlyR As Integer
Public BgDT As Integer
Public EnDT As Integer
Public DtFltr As Date


Public Function ObjectConnect(AAConn As String)

    ObjectConnect = AAConn

End Function

Public Sub NewConnect()

Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
Dim dlk As MSDASC.DataLinks

Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection
Set dlk = New MSDASC.DataLinks

    cnn.ConnectionString = dlk.PromptNew
    
        DoCmd.RunSQL (" DELETE Cred.* FROM Cred;")
        DoCmd.RunSQL ("INSERT INTO Cred ( ID, Nm ) SELECT  '" & cnn.ConnectionString & "' AS Expr1, '" & Environ("USERNAME") & "' As Exp2;")

Dim ns As ADODB.Connection
Set ns = New ADODB.Connection
    ns.ConnectionTimeout = 99000
    ns.CommandTimeout = 99000
    
    connector = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT Cred.ID FROM Cred;").Fields(0).Value
    'connector = cnn.ConnectionString
    
    ns.Open connector

Set cnn = Nothing
Set dlk = Nothing

End Sub

Public Sub Query_X()

'Err.Clear
'Debug.Print Err.Description

Dim txtN As String
Dim DL As String
Dim Query As String
Dim LogIDr As String

On Error GoTo GrpErr


Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    'rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient
    
    Query = QueryStringX
    'MsgBox Query

If Not (ns Is Nothing) Then
  If (ns.State And adStateOpen) = adStateOpen Then
    With rs
        .ActiveConnection = ns
        .Open Query
    End With
    
    'x = rs.Fields(0).Value
    
  End If
Else
    Set ns = New ADODB.Connection
        ns.ConnectionTimeout = 99000
        ns.CommandTimeout = 99000
        
        
    If Len(connector) < 1 Then
    ObjectConnect connector
    End If
        ObjectConnect connector
        ns.Open connector
        With rs
            .ActiveConnection = ns
            .Open Query
        End With
    End If
    
    'Debug.Print Err.Description
    GrpErr:
    If Len(Err.Description) > 2 Then
        Debug.Print "Error occured in " & IIf(FlyR = 0, "GQI_", "ABK_") & GRPcntR & ": " & Err.Description
        Err.Clear
    End If
    
    GRPcntR = GRPcntR + 1
    
    End Sub
```

Comment: Not an answer, just an observation: when you have `a RIGHT JOIN b` then a date filter on `a` belongs in the `ON` clause; putting it in a `WHERE` clause makes it logically an `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: Thanks!  I just took the code I was given and ran with it because there are over 200 separate queries.  I scanned it to get a feel for what it was doing and what I saw made me cringe.